# In regexes, does dot-star (.*) match spaces?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, match

Sorry this is a simple question but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

I'm going through Automate the Boring Stuff and I'm on Chapter 7 which is about Regexes.

It says .* matches any character except a newline, does that include a space?

Comment: Why not just try it and see?

Comment: Yeah that occurred to me like 30 seconds after I posted this

Comment: Well, the answer is: Yes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I could've just tested this in Python shell instead of posting here.

Yes, (.*) matches spaces

Comment: Paraphrasing the song: "Deletion is painless and brings on many changes."